# Find the rows which are in data.frame 1 but no in data.frame 2

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

I have one data.frame (Data) and a subset of this data.frame (Data2)

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10), 
  Diag1 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag2 = sample(c("D123", "E123", "F123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag3 = sample(c("G123", "H123", "I123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag4 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag5 = sample(c("J123", "K123", "L123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag6 = sample(c("M123", "N123", "O123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  Diag7 = sample(c("P123", "Q123", "R123"), 10, replace = TRUE))

Data2 <- Data[1:4,]
```

How do I get the "difference" of both data.frames?
I am looking for the rows which are in Data but not in Data2.

I thought something like this 
Data[!Data2]
should have worked but it didn't.

Thank you!

Comment: the `Data[!Data2]`  style syntax works with `data.table`s but not `data.frame`s, but requires `.( )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your exact problem here, but it can probably be generalized using the `count` function from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(Data, Data2)) # rbind data sets
df <- count(df, vars = names(df))       # count frequency of rows
subset(df, freq < 2)                    # subset the data.frame when freq < 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're using `data.table` constructs on `data.frame`. This should work instead -

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(Data)
Data2 <- data.table(Data2)

setkeyv(Data,colnames(Data))
setkeyv(Data2,colnames(Data2))

Data[!Data2]
```

Comment: I'll remove my answer since they're essentially the same

Comment: Thank you! I can see that it works with my example and will vote it as solved. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my actual example.

The two data frames are called SCICases4 which contains 11329 rows and SCICasesWoF (10914 rows) which are subsets I extracted from SCICases4 and put together with rbind. I tried to figure out what was left (the rows i didn't subset). I've got 189 variables. If i type SCICases4 [!SCICasesWoF] I just get SCICases4 back (obviously after running the other lines you proposed). 
> mode: "list"
> class: "data.table" "data.frame"
Any ideas?

Comment: The `setkeyv` part is indexing on some sort of combination across the `data.table`s. If you've added more columns to `SCICasesWoF` then you need to pass a vector with the right column names to `setkeyv`, instead of passing `colnames()`.

Comment: Both data frames have the same number of columns with the same column names. Might it be a problem that I randomly chose rows and but them together later on? It's not that I removed a complete block like it appears in the original post. I try again. Probably I did something wrong. Thx for fast replay!

Comment: Can you post the exact 4-5 lines of code you're running for the `Data[!Data2]` part?

Comment: SCICases4 <- as.data.table(SCICases4)
SCICasesWoF <- as.data.table(SCICasesWoF)

setkeyv(SCICases4,colnames(SCICases4))
setkeyv(SCICasesWoF,colnames(SCICasesWoF))

xxx <- SCICases4[!SCICasesWoF]

Comment: `key(SCICases4) == key(SCICasesWoF)`?

Comment: key(SCICases4) == key(SCICasesWoF)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
[177] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
And all the others in between true as well

Comment: I'll need to look at the data. Why don't you try doing Data[!Data2[1]], Data[!Data2[2]], Data[!Data[3]], etc. to see which row is causing problems?

Comment: It's not working with a single rows i tried. I can send you a sample of my data.frame if you like. Anyhow I don't want you to do my work, so just in case you are interested.

Comment: That's the spirit. I would first try to see if any operation performed on SCICasesWoF might have changed the data, datatype, or something that might affect the comparison being made in `Data[!Data2]`. Good luck.

Comment: @roccer, the code above is missing the `.( )`.  I'll go ahead and undelete my answer

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, how is `Data[!.(Data2)]` different from `Data[!Data2]`?

Comment: I hope it's not rude to do that but i unaccepted this answer since for my real problem maloneypatr delivered the answer that worked. I can't figure out why your approach didn't work with my problem while it perfectly worked here.

Comment: Personally, I'm not very impressed with @maloneypatr's solution because it's not very efficient. Can you try merging Data and Data2 with `all = TRUE` and see how many rows that returns? Otherwise, I think we're missing a step somewhere which I can't tell without looking at your exact code and data.

Comment: Yes that might be. But it still didn't even take me a second which is acceptable for my purpose. Data (SCICases4) has 11329 rows and 189 variables, Data2 (SCICasesWoF) has 10803 rows and 189 variables (same). merge(SCICases4, SCICasesWoF,all = TRUE) has 11329 rows. From Data, I extracted observations with  28 formulas like this: SCICases4[apply(SCICases4,1,function(x) {any( grep("AG", SCICases4$X_1_1_V04, value=TRUE) %in% x)}),] Then I bound the fragments i got with rbind.

Answer (score 4):

data.table keys are your (best!) friend

```
library(data.table)

Data  <- as.data.table(Data)
Data2 <- as.data.table(Data2)

## set whichever cols make sense as keys
setkey(Data, Diag1, Diag2, Diag3)  
## or to set all columns as key, use  
#  setkey(Data)

## Same key for Data2
setkey(Data2, Diag1, Diag2, Diag3)  
## or 
# setkeyv(Data2, key(Data))  # <~ Note: Use setkeyv for strings


Data[!.(Data2)]

   id Diag1 Diag2 Diag3 Diag4 Diag5 Diag6 Diag7
1:  5  A123  F123  G123  C123  K123  M123  Q123
2: 10  A123  F123  H123  B123  L123  N123  R123
3:  9  B123  E123  I123  C123  L123  N123  P123
4:  6  C123  E123  H123  C123  L123  M123  P123
5:  7  C123  F123  G123  C123  J123  M123  Q123
```